# GTK and SFML 2 Blurred sprites

Tags: gtk, sfml, sprite, blurry, drawingarea

I want to use GTK+ and SFML 2.0 together. I created a simple window to test that, but doesn't work well. Sprites are blurred. Below is a screenshot describing the problem.
/edit:
**The window renders only the first pixel of a texture.**

[image: GTK+ SFML problem]

It should look like this:

[image]

The code:

```cpp
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <gdk/gdkwin32.h>

sf::RenderWindow Win;
sf::Sprite tile[ MAP_SIZE ][ MAP_SIZE ];

void on_expose( GtkWidget * widget, gpointer data )
{
    MapView * view =( MapView * ) data;
    sf::Event event;
    while( Win.pollEvent( event ) )
    {
        if( event.type == sf::Event::Closed )
             Win.close();

        view->updateEvents( & event, Win );
    }

    Win.clear( sf::Color::White );
    view->render( tile, Win );
    Win.display();

    gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    sf::Texture tex; // Testing texture
    if( !tex.loadFromFile( "gfx/7.png" ) )
         std::cout << "Unable to load texture!\n";

    for( int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; ++i )
    for( int j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE; ++j )
         tile[ j ][ i ].setTexture( tex ); // Default texture, a.k.a MAP_NONE

    MapView view( tile, sf::Vector2f( 0, 0 ) );

    gtk_init( & argc, & argv );

    GtkWidget * window;
    GtkWidget * area;

    window = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
    area = gtk_drawing_area_new();

    gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER( window ), area );

    GdkEventMask mask;
    mask = GDK_ALL_EVENTS_MASK;
    gtk_widget_add_events( area, mask );

    gtk_widget_set_can_focus( area, true );
    gtk_widget_set_size_request( area, 16 * 25, 16 * 25 ); // Preview size.

    gtk_widget_realize( area );
    gtk_widget_set_double_buffered( area, false );

    Win.create( sf::WindowHandle( GDK_WINDOW_HWND( area->window ) ) ); // Windows-only solution
    Win.setFramerateLimit( 30 );

    g_signal_connect( window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK( gtk_main_quit ), NULL );
    g_signal_connect( area, "expose-event", G_CALLBACK( on_expose ), & view );

    gtk_widget_show_all( window );
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a screenshot that shows the problem you're describing? You mentioned that "sprites are blurred" but there aren't any sprites at all in your screen shot. Also, I would suggest that you reduce your code example to the most minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. There is no need for this `MapView` class.

Comment: What if you produce an example where you only draw a single image to the `RenderTarget`? That way we can keep focused on SFML + GTK problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to call

```
gdk_window_resize(area->window, MAP_SIZE*25, MAP_SIZE*25);
```

before creating a SFML window inside **drawing-area**.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess:

Use the second argument of `sf::Sprite::setTexture` to correctly reset the size of the sprite.

```
for( int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; ++i )
    for( int j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE; ++j )
        tile[ j ][ i ].setTexture( tex, true );
```

Comment: Sorry, but It does nothing :/

Comment: ok, so I guess you should try what Zack suggested: create a minimal app that displays only one sprite.

Comment: I found the problem, OpenGL context probably has 1x1 size. App shows first pixel of first sprite.

Comment: @user2221315 Could you provide the code required to fix the issue? In other words, the code you'll need to set the context to the correct size? That way other people can fix the problem too :)

Comment: But I don't know how can I fix it :/